# Can I use Stephen Hawking's name in my Science fiction book?

Tags: copyright, plagiarism

I wrote a science fiction book in which, Alien species comes on earth and they meet with Dr. Stephen Hawking.
Is it legal to use his name for the book?

Comment: If your book is set in the present day, those aliens are gonna have a hard time meeting with him...

Comment: IANYL (I Am Not Your Lawyer) but if I were I would ask if it is strictly necessary that you employ a fictional version of a famous real person. Why not creating our own famous fictional scientist?

Comment: It's very important for the plot

Comment: Is there any reason it has to *specifically* be Stephen Hawking? Can you not use another famous scientist?

Comment: Yes there's a reason. But I am putting no negative side of it